# Can not use restored data on new portainer (docker swarm): Environment is unreachable

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swarm, portainer

I have a single server with Portainer (docker swarm, one simple node). I am going to migrate it to another server so I took a backup and restored it successfully but can not connect to the new primary environment. It says:

> Failed loading environment Environment is unreachable. Connect to
> another swarm manager.

There is no special configuration I just used 'swarm init' during Portainer installation process. I generally know it is a problem with the manager and agent on the new server but I don't know what should I do to make it work.

Here is the log:
dial tcp: lookup tasks.agent on 172.26.0.2:53: no such host"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by transferring 'volumes' folder to the new server!